# Requires SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

**I have one problem that's causing more problems.**

*Let me explain what's going on:*

For the past week, wanted to learn ASP.NET MVC and develop an app.

To get my machine ready, installed:

> Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 32/64-bit (Multilanguage)
>
> SQL Server 2016 Enterprise With Service Pack 1 64-bit (English)

So, after that, I thought to be good to go.

This is the app I'm using to do the learning: [APP](https://github.com/spastnudel/MVA-Introduction-to-ASPNET-MVC/tree/master/MVCMusicStore).

Then, once I open in Visual Studio, this is what happens first:

[image]

Didn't really understand this message. but my thought remained: how can I open using SQL Server 2016?

This "problem" quickly vanished with:

Ok, let's still try to do a build and see what goes on:

[image]

Cool, I'm able to see the app.

Well, now that I'm in a "lucky day", let's test to register:

[image]

This last error has to do with the protocols selected for the server.

It has to do with MS SQL Server configuration. Which means, I may need to install additional ODBC drivers for MS SQL.

***How can I fix this and be able to register*?**

**Note:** If there's any info you might find important in order to understand how to help me with this problem, let me know. This because I'm a noob in the field, just getting started.

[Here is the course I've been following](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses-embed/introduction-to-aspnet-mvc-8322/-Introduction-to-Authentication-mNEz7Aay_4804984382).

Comment: If you look in the web.config file you'll see that the database is supposed to be an instance of localdb. You either need to install localdb as the error says, or,  as you've suggested that you have Sql 2016 installed, point your connection string to that instance.

Comment: LocalDB is a feature requires SQL Server Express. It's not available in the Enterprise edition. You need to instal SQL Server 2016 Express side-by-side with Enterprise. If you *don't* care about localdb, just create and use a database in server and modify the connection string accordingly

Comment: PS: You should probably use SQL Server Developer edition, not Enterprise. It has the same features as Enterprise but doesn't expire like an Enterprise Trial. It's also free, where a licensed Enterprise is rather expensive

Comment: I have free software from the university because of `DreamSpark Premium`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create a database in your SQL Server 2016 and then update your connection string to use that database.

Your connection string should look like

```
Server={server name},1433;Database=tiagoleft.music_shop.dbo;User ID={user id};Password={your_password_here};Trusted_Connection=False;E‌​ncrypt=True;Connecti‌​on Timeout=30;
```

Note: while installing, if you configured only windows authentication, then you have to update the connection string to use windows authentication. For that to work, replace the user id and password from the above string with

```
Integrated Security=True
```

Comment: so, if the DB is called: `tiagoleft.music_shop.dbo` , how can it look like the connection string?

Comment: If you are not sure, you can see the server name in the SQL server management studio

Comment: My Pleasure to help

Comment: Had this for the first time I can remember... opening a Visual Studio 2017 project in Visual Studio 2022... was expecting a complicated solution, changed the DB instance and it resolved the issue... don't get this with other projects... pretty odd.